# CSS(SASS) element not able to center

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a popup card, but the card isn't getting vertically aligned. I've used the `position: absolute;` for positioning but the card is showing down at the bottom.

CSS(SASS)

```
.popup {
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba($color-black, 0.8);
  z-index: 3000;
  &__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 75%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: $color-white;
    box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba($color-black, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Popup is not fully implemented, I was checking where the element would show up.
This code is showing a white box down at the bottom instead of middle. Where I was hoping it to be.

HTML

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup__content">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

The `popup` class is direct child of `body` just so it isn't influenced by any other classes. Anyone see where I might screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.popup {
 height: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba($color-black, 0.8);
  z-index: 3000;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  &__content {
    
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 75%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: $color-white;
    box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba($color-black, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using display: flex with justify-content, align-items rather than position: fixed.
It will be a constructive choice for a comfortable future in the future.

Please refer to the following URL through Google Translator. This site is well detailed.

https://heropy.blog/2018/11/24/css-flexible-box/

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` also for the child container (`&__content`). `position: absolute;` relates to he next higher ancestor with `position: relative`, so that night not be appropriate in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.popup {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 3000;
  }
  .popup__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem green;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup__content">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```